# Parsley.JS Form Validation Issues

Tags: parsley.js, parsley

I am using Parsley JS for form validation but I don't know what I am missing. Right now, HTML5 is doing the validation part of it. I would be truly grateful if someone can assist because I am racking my brain and cannot figure it out.

Here is my code.

**Form Only Code:**

http://hastebin.com/ecofitidir.html

**Full Page Code:**

http://hastebin.com/etawaduqif.html

**Website:**

www.polarpos.com/contacttest/application.php

Comment: Here is the website:

www.polarpos.com/contacttest/application.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[your code is ok, by the way do not use any js script just the parsley.min.js and data attr!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgH8C.png)

Comment: So should I just remove jquery and bootstrap?

Comment: No don't remove an files just the js code you have included at the bottom of your file

Comment: No, don't remove any files just the js code you have included at the bottom of your file

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you so very much. I really appreciate it.

I really hope you don't mind if I post again about this, I got a few other forms.

Comment: I am happy your problem has been solved, I don't mind to help you at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i have tried your code and the validation works perfect. try to download the parsley.min.js again and make sure your scripts like so :

Your code is fine don't change it.
and by the way it does not need any ja code to work. here's my code. i have tried it on laravel project of mine

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot of it appears to you?

It should appear like it does in this example:

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: i have added a screenshot to my answer have you seen it?